# Solving inhomogeneous ODE - using Duhamels principle

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I want to solve following ODE:

$a (-b u(x_2)+\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2})+c x_2 (-b u(x_2)+\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2})-d(\frac{\partial^4 u(x_2)}{x_2^4}-2b\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2}+b^2u(x_2))=f(x_2)$

I know that the homogoneour solution could be found as an Airy function. However due to the inhomogenity which is of "complex strucutre" consisting also of intregral over Airy functions and exponential terms, I do not know how to solve the ODE.

I know that Duhamels principle is oftentimes used to solve inhomogenoeus ODEs.

Duhamels principle states as follow:

$u_t(x,t)-L u(x,t)=f(x,t)\\
u(x,0=)\\
\rightarrow u(x,t)=\int_0^t (P^sf)(x,t)ds$

where $P^s f$ is the solution to:

$u_t-Lu=0\\
u(x,s)=f(x,s)$

I want to know whether I can use a similar approach to solve my linear ODE, which does not have constant coefficients and which does not have homogenous boundary conditions?

I would appreciate any kind of help.